# How to subtract in Map Reduce paradigm

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing, emr, elastic-map-reduce

I have the following dataset

```
s1, s2, count
1, 2, x1
1, 3, x2
1, 4, x3
2, 1, y1
2, 3, y2
2, 4, y3
3, 1, z1
3, 2, z2
```

I want to get the following output

```
s1, s2, count
1, 2, x1-y1
1, 3, x2-z1
1, 4, x3
2, 3, y2-z2
2, 4, y3
```

The idea is that s1 is an entity which is favored over s2. And I have tuples such that s1 (say = 1) was favored over s2 (say = 2) by x1 times AND s1 (say = 2) was favored over s2 (say = 1) by y1 times. What I need is a sub O(n^2) algorithm to compute absolute number of times s1 was favored over s2 (or other way round). (x1-y1)

The problem is that there are 230 million such tuples and I can't have O(n^2) algorithm to compute this.

One observation is that the tuples are sorted on s1 since they are results of another MR output.

Please help me find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the "favoring." It looks as though you want to subtract values where the `s1`, `s2` values are the same.

You can define a custom `Comparable` / `Writable`, let's call it `S1S2Writable`, that encapsulates `(s1, s2)` as a tuple and states the two tuples are equal when

```
((tuple1.s1 == tuple2.s1 && tuple2.s1 == tuple2.s2) ||
    (tuple1.s1 == tuple2.s2 && tuple2.s2 == tuple2.s1))
```

With that, you can define a process using `Mapper<S1S2Writable, IntWritable, S1S2Writable, IntWritable>` to read your input file, and pass it to a `Reducer<S1S2Writable, IntWritable, KEYOUT, IntWritable>`.

This will group the `S1S2Writable` with `Iterable<IntWritable>`, which you can perform a subtraction over.